# Lightning parsing error of related list

Tags: lightning

With lightning , I need to be able to transfer obects related list data from server to client then to client to server.

From server to client, it works correctly , the content of related list is well retrieved.

```
AccountFromServer: {
  "Name": "SomeAccount",
  "Id": "0013600000kJhmDAAS",
  "Contacts": [
    {
      "AccountId": "0013600000kJhmDAAS",
      "Id": "0033600000Xy9DyAAJ",
      "Name": "Contact1"
    },
    {
      "AccountId": "0013600000kJhmDAAS",
      "Id": "0033600000Xy9EDAAZ",
      "Name": "Contact2"
    },
    {
      "AccountId": "0013600000kJhmDAAS",
      "Id": "0033600000Xy9ESAAZ",
      "Name": "Contact3"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when i send the same data to the server again, the related list content is deleted.

```
AccountAfterServerTransfer: {
  "Id": "0013600000kJhmDAAS",
  "Name": "SomeAccount"
}
```

It feels to be a bug in SalesForce ... any chance it could be corrected soon ? It's a major blocking problem for our ISV development :/

Here is some code to simply reproduce the problem with a sample app & apex class

**Lightning app :**

```
<aura:application controller="ccAppNico">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="Account" type="Account" />

    <a onclick="{!c.doUpdate}">CLICK HERE</a>

</aura:application>

({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
        AccountName = 'SomeAccount';
        debugger;
        action.setParams({'AccountName':AccountName});
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            debugger;
            var acc = a.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.Account", acc);
            console.log('AccountFromServer: '+JSON.stringify(acc,null,2));
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    doUpdate : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.setAccount"); 
        debugger;
        action.setParams({'acc':component.get('v.Account')});
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            debugger;
            var acc = a.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.Account", acc);
            console.log('AccountAfterServerTransfer: '+JSON.stringify(acc,null,2));
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex controller :**

```
public class ccAppNico {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccount(String AccountName)
    {
        List<Account> AccountList = [select Name,(select id,Name from Contacts) from Account where Name=:AccountName limit 1] ;
        Account acc = AccountList[0];
        System.debug(acc);
        System.debug(acc.Contacts);
        return acc ;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account setAccount(Account acc)
    {
        System.debug(acc);
        System.debug(acc.Contacts);
        return acc ;
    }    
}
```

Many many thanks & best regards

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you can send objects deeper than 1 level as parameters when calling a server side action. I suggest you send as a string and deserialize in the apex method, or send as separate params.

Rekated issue: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005GiwIAE